# *this makes a call to constructor?

Tags: c++

Does the operation on "this" pointer calls the constructor ?

I have a constructor defined as follows

```
    Cents(int cents)
    {
            cout<<"in cents constructor\n";
            m_cents = cents;
    }

    friend Cents operator + (const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2)
    {           
            return Cents(c1.m_cents + c2.m_cents);
    }

    Cents operator ++ (int)
    {
            cout<<"In c++ function\n";
            Cents c(m_cents);
            *this = *this + 1 ;
            return c;
    }
```

in main function I have sth like...

```
    Cents c;
    cout<<"Before post incrementing\n";
    c++; //This part is calling the constructor thrice
```

Now If I am doing some operation like `*this = *this + 1`. 
It calls this constructor twice.

What exactly is going on here. Does `*this` creates a temp object and assigns the value to the original object?

Comment: Please show us more code. Do you have copy constructor and assignment operator defined?

Comment: @RafałRawicki....No I dont have any copy constructor or assignment operator defined.

Comment: Could you post the complete example? See http://sscce.org I think, the Cents constructor should be called once in this expression, not twice.

Comment: Please show us the exact code for this class, including the `operator +()` and the method that includes the curious `*this = *this + 1`. It's unfair to expect us to guess.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet. I was just checking ...please dont go with the logic of the code i.e what I am trying to do with *this = *this +1 step.

Comment: I see, implicit conversion calls constructor once and operator+ calls the constructor once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, **dereferencing a pointer doesn't create any new object**.

Hovever, if you have `operator+` defined only for instances of your class, there will be a **new instance constructed from** `1`, because the constructor `Cents(int cents)` isn't marked as explicit.

Comment: can you please elaborate it a little :)

Answer (score 3):

You've a whole lot of contsructions going on here!

```
Cents c;
```

This line calls `Cents::Cents()`, which is synthesised by the compiler and may not do what you want it to.

Then you call:

```
Cents Cents::operator++(int)
```

Which returns an object and explicitly makes a call to `Cents::Cents(int)`.

Then you do your curious assignment, which makes the second call to `Cents::Cents(int)` for the second argument.

When you call `Cents operator+(const Cents&, const Cents&)` you explicitly construct a new one `Cents::Cents(int)` and return a copy of it...

Then you call the synthesised `Cents& Cents::operator=(const Cents&)`, which again may not do what you want it to.

A typical post-increment operator would look like this:

```
Cents& operator++(int)
{
    Cents rv = *this;

    ++m_cents;

    return rv;
}
```

Notice how it returns the value of the class as it was before the increment by calling the copy constructor (rather than an override) and also how it increments the members of the class individually.